# Imported video is extremely choppy in Premiere Pro CC 2019

Tags: premiere

Ok, so I've imported a QuickTime movie file into Premiere, and when I played it in the preview window, it was really choppy, and it played the first three seconds over and over for the entirety of the video. I put it into the timeline and the same thing happened, the audio worked perfectly, but the video kept lagging behind and cutting up periodically, I've had this problem to a lesser extent with after effects, but nowhere near as bad as it is in Premiere, I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the playback resolution to a lower setting. Depending on your periphery and the footage you're handling, it is quite normal for premiere to lag behind the realtime playback. Solutions for fluent playback might be:

- Lowering the playback resolution (1/2, 1/4 or 1/16)
- Using Proxies (smaller files, usually half the resolution. A quick google search tells you how to do that.)
- Giving Premiere more RAM to play with and cleaning your cache.

  -> You might need to go to edit -> purge and select purge all. Cached frames are frames that sit on a harddrive on your pc, so they don't have to be calculated every time they're played. Other then caching on the harddrive, premiere also caches into the RAM (random access memory) which acts like a very fast harddrive (although much smaller). Depending on how much RAM you can afford to assign to premiere (usually half as much as your total ram, preferably more than 8GB) you should up the amount dedicated to premiere. This setting sit in the memory section of the settings.

Comment: Okay so i did exactly this, I gave it another shot and it still doesn't work, I also tried a couple more proposed solutions like rebooting premiere, rebooting my computer, deleting the file and making a new one, converting the file into a different type, updating premiere, even deleting premiere and reinstalling, and using a different computer, and the problem still persists. I might as well just end it right now. The strangest thing is that at one point the issue solved itself for no apparent reason, and it exported fine, but when I opened the original premiere file the problem came back.